# How can I acces external memory of a 80C51

Tags: c, memory-management, 8051

I am writing software for a 80C51 chip and when I declared 2 arrays of 64 bytes I suddenly got me an errorcode 254. Meaning I used all my ram.

[image]

The chip has so called external memory but I don't know how to use it. I am programming it in C in the mcu 8051 IDE. I tried typing 'far' and 'xdata' in front of the variabeles,but that does not compile.

Must I include a separate header file or something?

Comment: External memory typically means external memory circuits outside the chip, on the same board.

Comment: "External memory" can mean many things. Is it supposed to be ROM (of some variant) or RAM? It's not mapped into the address-space? What does the documentation say?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043888/when-do-i-use-xdata

Comment: @lkj This helped. I was right to use xdata. However googling some more I had to enable xdata by editing my project. I have done so, but the compiler still tosses me a syntax error when trying to use xdata and I have tried every every upper/lower case combo though it should be lower case only.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The external memory is external ram and it is on-chip.

Answer (score 0):

I had to type 2 underscores before xdata, this was almost nowhere to be found on the internet